# XSLT character escaping

Tags: c#, xslt, escaping

I have the following item name in my xml to be transformed

```
<title>abc \" &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;</title>
```

Which I transform using the following in my XSL file:

```
<xsl:attribute name="itemTitle"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:attribute>
```

I am using C# 's XSLCompiledTransform's Transform function. My code is:

```
XPathDocument xpTemplate = new XPathDocument("articlesLookupTemplate.xsl");
XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
xsl.Load(xpTemplate);

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlData))
{
    xsl.Transform(XmlReader.Create(reader), xslArg, output);
}
```

where output is a HtmlTextWriter.
After transforming it through XSLT I want it to remain escaped, i.e the output should remain

```
itemTitle="abc&quot; &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;"
```

However what I get is :

```
itemTitle="abc&quot;><script>alert(1)</script>"
```

I am using the html output method in my xsl file and have no disable-output-escaping. If I try the text output method I get a truncated output. How can I ensure that the text remains as it is.

--- Update ---
i tried my xsl and xml on www.xmlper.com

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="/articles">
<table id="TemplateTable">
     <xsl:for-each select="articletemplate">
        <li class="Dialog-ListItem">
           <xsl:attribute name="itemTitle"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>  
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and XML file being:

```
<articles >
  <articletemplate>  
  <title>abc " &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;</title>
  </articletemplate>
</articles>
```

For the one in xmlattribute I get

```
itemTitle="abc &quot; > < script > alert(1) < /script >"
```

and for the one without it I get

```
abc " &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;
```

I wanted the one inside xmlattribute to also be encoded.

Comment: You can't really compare the output from xmlper.com unless you know they are using the same Xml Processor as you. Do you have a simple XML sample you could post please?

Comment: The xml sample is:
    <articles >
    <articletemplate>  
     <title>abc " &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;</title>
    </articletemplate>
    </articles>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let me comment on your output; you are using the following:

```
<table id="TemplateTable">
     <xsl:for-each select="articletemplate">
        <li class="Dialog-ListItem">
           <xsl:attribute name="itemTitle"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>  
</table>
```

Which will be producing an `li` as a child of `table` - this is not good HTML (and certainly wouldn't validate when I tried it on w3c.org). `<li>` should really be a child of `<ul>` or `<ol>`

With that out of the way, this is actually quite an interesting question. I believe the reason for it is due to a disagreement with the specification:

> The html output method should not escape < characters occurring in
>   attribute values.

(Source: http://www.xm.co.nz/ShoXS/xsloutput.htm)

Here's what I think is happening:

The xsl:value-of in the parser sees `abc \&quot; &amp;gt; &amp;lt; script &amp;gt; alert(1) &amp;lt; /script &amp;gt;` which it immediately translates to `abc \&quot; > < script > alert(1) < /script >`. Then, according to the rule above, this should be placed verbatim into the attribute value (which is what I've observed too).

This is almost certainly due to the html output declaration. If I change the output to be XML, the values are placed into the attribute verbatim.

So you have two options:

1. Transform straight to XML (by changing your output to be `xml`) and attempt to write that out to the client. It might be XML, but if you send it as HTML (by omitting the XML declaration and using the correct content type for HTTP) then it should be written as expected.
2. Place your text as CDATA: `<![CDATA[abc " &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;]]>` - this appears to force the .Net Xml parser to not treat the text as HTML (so it does not get translated prior to being output when the output method is `html`) and the result is as you desire

It's also interesting to note that `disable-output-escaping` has no effect here. This is almost certainly due to the interpretation of the spec when the output method is `html`

Tested using XmlDocument, XSLTransform, .Net 3.5

Here is the XSLT I wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/articles/articletemplate" />
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="articletemplate">
    <li class="Dialog-ListItem" itemTitle="{title}">
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The sample XML I used (note CDATA vs non-CDATA):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<articles>
  <articletemplate>
    <title><![CDATA[abc \" &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;]]></title>
  </articletemplate>
  <articletemplate>
    <title>abc " &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;</title>
  </articletemplate>
  <articletemplate>
    <title>test</title>
  </articletemplate>
</articles>
```

And the output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="Dialog-ListItem" itemTitle="abc \&quot; &amp;gt; &amp;lt; script &amp;gt; alert(1) &amp;lt; /script &amp;gt;">abc \" &amp;gt; &amp;lt; script &amp;gt; alert(1) &amp;lt; /script &amp;gt;</li>
      <li class="Dialog-ListItem" itemTitle="abc &quot; > < script > alert(1) < /script >">abc " &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;</li>
      <li class="Dialog-ListItem" itemTitle="test">test</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for responding.  
In my original html I do have the `<li>` as a child of `<ul>`, I trimmed it along with some more tags here to shorten the xsl.  

1. You are right about using xml as the output is the same. I will have to check if using Xml does not break anything else.  

2. CDATA encodes the special characters but it converts the original `&gt;` to `&amp;gt;` , that is it reencodes the escaped characters !  

Thanks.

Comment: @fuehrer - yes, that's a consequence of HTML output (but should appear as expected in the browser). I'll add a bit more to my answer.

Comment: I just realized that I can't change the XML file's data to add CDATA to it so I will have to try with changing the output method to XML or there is some goofy way you can add CDATA through XSL itself ?

Comment: @feuhrer Sadly not. Output Method = XML is perfectly valid - you should really be aiming for HTML output that is XHTML anyway (which output method = `xml` will move you some way towards).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to retain the original form of the attribute value, because the XSLT processor does not know what the original form is; the entity references in the attribute value are expanded by the XML parser and handed to the XSLT processor in their "expanded" form (that is, `&lt;` is conevrted to `<` and so on). The final result of xsl:value-of then depends on the HTML serialization method, which is free to output '"' within an attribute value as either `&quot;` or `&#34;` or in various other eqivalent ways. I haven't investigated carefully whether outputting '<' and '>' in unescaped form in HTML is legitimate or not - my first instict is that it isn't legitimate, and this is a bug in your processor.

Comment: `<` isn't legitimate in an attribute value, `>` is, though best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your problem.

On www.xmlper.com, I got output:

```
<t itemTitle="abc \&quot; &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;" />
```

And with Saxon, I got output:

```
<t itemTitle="abc \&#34; &gt; &lt; script &gt; alert(1) &lt; /script &gt;"/>
```

I don't see how it is possible to get what you claim you have got. Either your XSLT processor is non-conformant, or you have confused the value of the output attribute as some DOM parser reports it, with the lexical rendering of the output attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.
I have added details for the transformation in the question. I am checking the output by writing the HtmlTextWriter to a StreamWriter and checking the file written to.

Comment: Then that is your problem. You are not looking at the XSLT output. The XSLT output will be correct. Your down-stream manipulation of it is at fault.

Comment: Thanks again, but since I am a XSLT n00b, could you guide me how to view the XSLT output. The code that I have uses a HtmlTextWriter as the output steam for the transformation which I send to a StreamWriter to address your concern about not seeing the XSLT output.

Comment: I know a little bit about XSLT, but I know absolutely zero about C#, HtmlTextWriter and StreamWriter. I don't even know what StreamWriter is. You probably need to get the C# experts involved. Dr. Kay's answer is suggesting that it is your goal to get ...&lt;script&gt;... etc as the **decoded** value of your output (and therefore the lexical value as ..&amp;lt;script&&amp;gt;... . Whereas in contrast I have understood that you want ...<script>... as the **decoded** output (and hence &lt;script&gt; as the **lexical** value. Perhaps you need to clarify?

Comment: You are being of great help :)
I used the site you mentioned www.xmlper.com and have posted my results on it in the question.